# Unable to uninstall nginx on Mac OS X

Tags: nginx, uninstallation

Output of `nginx -v`:
`nginx version: nginx/1.14.0`.

After running `brew uninstall nginx` or `brew remove nginx`, it gives error:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx
```

I have tried :

```
rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
rm -f -R /usr/local/etc/nginx
rm -r /usr/local/opt/nginx
```

But still `nginx -v` giving output: `nginx version: nginx/1.14.0`

How can I remove the nginx installation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check path with `which nginx` 
Then, you can remove from that path.

Answer (score 1):

Update your local filesystem db on Mac, this will take of any links in the system,

sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb