# unable to uninstall nginx from macos

Tags: nginx

I tried running `sudo killall nginx` as advised here [Unable to uninstall nginx on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51890765/unable-to-uninstall-nginx-on-mac-os-x) and I get `no matching processes were found`. I don't see an nginx binary nor is it seemingly installed through homebrew. yet, when I go to 127.0.0.1 or localhost, I see nginx. I tried to clear my browser cache and three different browsers but it shows the same thing. I'm trying to run a site locally using apache2 and it worked just fine a moment ago. but once I rebooted, I'm now seeing this nginx nonsense.